# Why am i getting this error using tidymodels? Error: Object '.' not found (R)

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am very new to R and tidymodels but I am almost certain what im doing is correct here and yet i get the error: object '.' not found. (in the fit function) Everything is up to date.

```
set.seed(1234)

gss16_rec_1 <- recipe(advfront ~ educ, data = gss16_train) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), one_hot = TRUE)

gss16_rec_1_prep <- prep(gss16_rec_1)

gss16_mod_1 <- logistic_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glm")

gss16_wflow_1 <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(gss16_rec_1) %>%
  add_model(gss16_mod_1)

gss16_fit_1 <- gss16_wflow_1 %>% fit(data = gss16_train)
```

I've been through a lot of other similar posts but nothing works the error persists

Comment: what packages are you using, can you share your data? it is hard to help with out more information

Comment: for curiosity, what made you choose `all_nominal()` over `all_nominal_predictors()`? if that is recommended somewhere i would like to know so we can get that changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `all_nominal()` selects the outcome `advfront` and creates dummies from it, making it such that there is no outcome for `logistic_reg()`.

Change `all_nominal()` to `all_nominal_predictors()` and you should be good to go.

In the next CRAN versions of these packages, will have the following hopefully better error message:

```r
Error:
! `logistic_reg()` was unable to find an outcome.
ℹ Ensure that you have specified an outcome column and that it 
  hasn't been removed in pre-processing.
```

Comment: Hey everyone thanks for the help, problem was solved through any of the solutions posted by others. Another way to fix the error would be to add -all_outcomes() to the step dummy. (if anyone ever has the same issue and sees this post)